# Follow hyperlink using the VBA

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-word

How to follow hyperlinks in Microsoft Word 2016?

This works fine in Excel:

```
' Works in Excel
Sub FollowURL()
    ActiveCell.Hyperlinks(1).Follow
End Sub
```

However, when I try to change `ActiveCell` to `Selection` (assuming it is necessary for Word), it doesn't work:

```
' Doesn't work in Word
Sub FollowURL()
    Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Follow
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
' Note: Ensure the selection contains "http://..."
' for example: http://www.google.com

ActiveDocument.FollowHyperlink Selection.Text
```

**Note:** That you check your firewall to let word use this function as @john c. j. mentioned in the comments.

Comment: It gives me an error (I use Word 2016). Does it work for you?

Comment: @johnc.j. It would be helpful to provide the error message. Yes it works form me. Ensure the selection contains `http://...`

Comment: Run-time error 4198: Command failed. Here is [screeenshot](http://i.imgur.com/oLR0Dnz.png)

Comment: I think you need to understand the `Selection` object of Microsoft Word. According to your screenshot I see the cursor in the middle of the URL (after the first w of the www). So the selected text is "". Means it's empty. The `Selection` object provides what you HAVE selected. The way you try it, the Selection is empty. Try with selecting the whole URL and it should work. If you want to also have it work when you only within a URL with your cursor I would first update your question with that new requirement.

Comment: Agreed, my knowledge is very limited. However, it seems I already tried it, and there was the same error. Here is [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/yXmqWZS.png).

Comment: I see. To what I googled I think this is another problem. Can you try to run the same macro on another machine and/or other Microsoft Word version? Also try to use only the function itself `ActiveDocument.FollowHyperlink "http://www.google.com"`

Comment: The function itself doesn't work, it gives the same error. Probably I should test it on another version of Word or on another computer, as you said.

Comment: Well, actually it works, and I approved it. Word was blocked in firewall, and that's why the error occured. Also, the link [should be valid](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?58852-To-fix-quot-Run-time-error-4198-Command-failed-quot-in-macro-to-open-hyperlinks) - it works for `http://www.google.com`, but it will not work for `http://www.djjkdbkjdbdkjdb.com` (some random letters in address).

Comment: Glad to hear, very good. I've updated the answer accordingly.