# Can't side-load add-in into MS Word on Windows

Tags: office-js

I am currently developing an [Microsoft Word Web Add-in](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/word/word-add-ins?product=word).

Since I use a Mac, I have downloaded a [Windows 10 VM](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/) and installed Office using my Office 365 subscription.

I can get Word Add-ins to run on Office 365 and Word for Mac, but not on Word 2016 for Windows.

I can't get Word 2016 on Windows 10 to run any add-ins, whether it is one I have written myself, or one downloaded from the store. Word always shows the Add-in frame with "loading" and then it just stays there; the add-in never loads.

I don't get the menu option to attach a debugger, and there are no obvious error messages.

Are there some restrictions to running Add-ins on VMs? Where do I start to debug this?

**EDIT:**

I just noticed that my own side-loaded add-in throws an error in a <del>popup</del> **dialog box** that opens *behind* Word, which then prevents word from opening further add-ins. So if I close the <del>popup</del> **dialog box**, then add-ins from the store work as expected. However I can't side-load my own add-ins.

The error I get is

> Cannot find `‘file://msedgewin10/manifest/boilerplate/home.html?_host_Info=Word$Win32$16.01$en-US’`. Make sure the path or Internet address is correct.

However if I paste this address into IE it opens the file with no complaints. Very strange.

Comment: Have you checked if maybe the option in the security center of Microsoft Word to deactivate all add-ins is ticked? I'm not aware of any restrictions to add-ins running in VM's.

Comment: Security settings _seem_ to be OK, although clearly I am having trouble reaching "file://msedgewin10/manifest/boilerplate/home.html?_host_Info=Word$Win32$16.01$en-US". Add-ins are activated, but there is a problem with my side-loaded add-in.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question. That reminds me to my other answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45938904/1306012 You need to add an exception for Microsoft Word in the firewall to follow links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here was the fix in case anybody is wondering:

My initial side-loaded add-in was creating an error that caused Word to create an error notification that popped up *behind* Word and then blocked execution of all subsequent add-ins. **All error popups had to be closed before add-ins would work again**

So actually my side-loaded add-in was broken, and this caused all subsequent add-ins not to work.

A bit of a silly error, but a head scratcher none-the-less.

Answer (score 1):

I've don't recommend using `file://` uris for side-loading. It is generally easier to use the [SMB Share method](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/create-a-network-shared-folder-catalog-for-task-pane-and-content-add-ins#share-a-folder) with Office for Windows. When I'm developing on a Mac I tend to share the `wef` directory from my Mac so my manifest changes show up in both Mac and Windows at the same time.

The popup issue is something different whoever. This is likely happening because your using JavaScript to open the popup (i.e. `window.open(...)`). Using this method results is very odd behavior due to the number of browsers and browser engines Office leverages for Add-ins.

For popups, you should *always* use the [Dialog API](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) included with Office.js. This API is custom tailored to work across every supported Office environment (Windows, Mac, iOS, Android, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE, Edge). It is particularly useful when you want to have parent/child communication between the add-in and the dialog; something not easily accomplished on Mac or Windows where the popup is running in an entirely different browser instance from the add-in.

One key tip when it comes to developing add-ins is to sign up for the [Office 365 Developer Program](https://dev.office.com/devprogram). This gives you access to a free Office 365 Developer tenant. While this may seem like overkill, it will greatly simplify your life as it allows you to use O365's [Centralized Deployment](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/publish/centralized-deployment) feature to instantly deploy your manifest across a number of Office clients (Windows, Mac, Online, etc.). When it comes to dev/test, it is a huge time saver. It also does some lightweight validation of your manifest which can catch some common mistakes.

Another tip is to use Azure Web Apps for hosting the add-in. This gives you a public URL and SSL cert out of the box (SSL is required by Office for all add-ins). The best part, you can run up to [10 Azure Web Apps for free](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/). I typically push my code up to the size as part of my add-ins build process. Azure supports publishing via [FTP/SFTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-deploy?toc=%2Fazure%2Fapp-service%2Ftoc.json#ftp), [continuous integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-deploy?toc=%2Fazure%2Fapp-service%2Ftoc.json#continuousdeployment) (VS Team Services, GitHub, or BitBucket) or even from a [local Git repository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-deploy-local-git?toc=%2Fazure%2Fapp-service%2Ftoc.json).

Comment: Hi Marc- just to clarify- Word was throwing an error message in a dialog box ("pop-under") that came into existence _behind_ Word, and silently blocked all add-in execution until I happened to minimise some windows and click "ok" on all the dialog boxes.

Thanks for the tip about "Office 365 Developer Program", I will check it out- dev/test on multiple platforms is really important for us.

Like many JS programmers, I currently find myself with a lot of  Windows/Office work, after years in OSX/*n*x territory- so tips would be great. Where should I go to chat with Office Add-In devs?